# How to draw a parabola using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a code sample which i need to edit in order to draw a parabola
using only one line of code at the place marked
can any one advise ?

```
<html>
  <body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0,0);
      for(var i=0;i<300;i++)
      {
          //i need to put one line of code here
      }
      ctx.stroke();
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can read about SVG. It will allow you to create virtually any parabola you need.

Comment: how about `ctx.lineTo(i, i*i)`?

Comment: Any parabola sufficient? I believe you must also consider coordinat e transformation if you want to draw a correct parabolic curve as in the paper.

Comment: ctx.lineTo(i, i*i) this answer will still draw a line

Comment: yes any parabola  i has to be inside the iteration only one line of code

Comment: Looks like homework? see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: i have tried this line  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(150, 150, 300, 0); it actual draw a parabola but i have remarked the iteration surrounded it  so its a wrong implementation

Comment: not sure i understand u what line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an open-up parabolic curve use

```js
x=300/2; y=150/2; a=+1; ctx.lineTo(i, y - a/300*(i-x)*(i-x))
```

where

- `x` is for center of parabola along horizontal direction,
- `y` is for base of parabola along vertical direction, due to canvas coordinate is different than ordinary coordinate, and chosen also in the middle,
- `a > 0` for open up,
- `a < 0` for open-down,
- `a = 0` for horizontal line.

You can simpy substitute the values to write a simple line

```js
ctx.lineTo(i, 75 - 1/300*(i-150)*(i-150))
```

but not so clear and not adjustable anymore.

**Edit** 
In order to get the formula, a [coordinate transformation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-to-viewport-transformation-in-computer-graphics-with-implementation/) must be applied.

```
Canvas coordinate (X, Y)
(0, 0) -----+
  |         |
  |         |
  +------ (w, h)
   
World coordinate (x, y)
  + ----- (c, d)
  |         |
  |         |
(e, b) ---- +

Transformation (x, y) -> (X, Y)
X = (x - e) / (c - e) * (w - 0) + 0
Y = (y - b) / (d - b) * (0 - h) + h

Canvas size
w = 300
h = 150

World coordinate ranges (only as example)
e = -1
b = -1
c = 1
d = 1

Use
X = (x - -1) / (1 - -1) * (300  - 0) + 0 = (x + 1) / 2 * 300
  = 150 * (x + 1)
x =  X / 150 - 1

Y = (y - -1) / (1 - -1) * (0 - 150) + 150 = (y + 1) / 2 * -150 + 150
  = -75 * (y + 1) + 150 = -75 * [ (y + 1) - 2]
  = -75 * (y - 1)
y = Y / -75 + 1
  = 1 - Y / 75

The equation is y = a * x * x
         y = a * x * x
1 - Y / 75 = a * (X / 150 - 1) * (X / 150 - 1)
   -Y / 75 = -1 + a * (X / 150 - 1) * (X / 150 - 1)

Y = 75 - 75 * a * (X / 150 - 1) * (X / 150 - 1)
  = 75 - 75 * a * (X / 150 - 1) * (X / 150 - 1) * 1
  = 75 - 75 * a * (X / 150 - 1) * (X / 150 - 1) * (150 * 150) / (150 * 150)
  = 75 - (1 / 300) * a * (X - 150) * (X - 150)
  
X is i
Y is 75 - a/300*(i-150)*(i-150)
```

Comment: thanks a lot:) that solved my problem appreciate your efforts

Comment: Hi dudung can u share how did u  came up with your  calculation of 75-1/150*(i-150)*(i-150) is it coming from a parabola formula
Y=ax^2+bx+c?

Comment: assuming you are using y=1*X^2 as your parabola equation
the first question would be
if ctx.lineTo(x,y) 
so based on the this equation y=1*X^2  you should put (x,1*(i-x)*(i-X))
so i dont realy understand   what the logic behind 
 a/150*(i-x)*(i-x) why did you divide a/150 
the second question is
based on the ctx.lineTo function  you e put i instead of x so according to i being increment it will be increment up to 300 and the parabola x coordinate pick is 150 
and than should be decreased again to 0  and in the i case (x coordinate) its only increasing  without being decreased back to 0

Comment: Values of 300 and 150 are related to canvas width and height. Actually I implement implicitly coordinate transformation. In our worl coordinate (xmin, ymin) is at lower left corner and (xmax, ymax) at upper right corner, while in canvas (0, ymax=height) is at lower left corner and (xmax=width, 0) is at upper right corner.  The given formula is for (0, 0) in our world coordinate at the position of center of canvas (width, height).

Comment: I correct the equation to 75-a/300*(i-150)*(i-150) and add the derivation of the equation. Actualy it is y = ax^2 in real world coordinate, but in canvas coordinate (due to transformation) it becomes 75-a/300*(i-150)*(i-150) if we choose the real world coordinate ranges is -1 < x < 1 and -1 < y <1. I hope the additional information sufficient.

Comment: now i get it there  is a conversion process needed  between the "world" to canvas i was missing that one :) thanks a lot for your detailed answer appreciate that